# Twitter like @ or # key search using bootstrap suggest

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Please suggest how can I search or autosuggest not only using @ but the # key as well in the same piece of script below. Any regex that simplifies the solution would be appreciated.

```
$('textarea').suggest('@', {
    // or an external JSON data file
    data: users,

    // style the autocomplete/autusuggest list
     map: function(user) {
          return {
            value: user.username,
            text: '<strong>'+user.username+'</strong> <small>'+user.fullname+'</small>'
          }
        }
      });
```

Link for the same is given here [Twitter Like @Mentions Auto Suggesting](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Twitter-Like-Mentions-Auto-Suggesting-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Suggest.html).
The problem with this is that I want @ and # both keys to be used as search pattern. But in the script above only @ is being used.

Comment: Don't know but in [DOC](http://lodev09.github.io/bootstrap-suggest/) they said: `$('#textarea').suggest({key: options, key2: options})` so i guess `.suggest({'@': optsObj, '#': optsObj});`  It would be easier for sure if `key` could be a regex or at least a string handling seperate keys by comma, space or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [DOC](http://lodev09.github.io/bootstrap-suggest/), you need to use:

```
var optsObj = {
  // or an external JSON data file
  data: users,

  // style the autocomplete/autusuggest list
  map: function(user) {
    return {
      value: user.username,
      text: '<strong>' + user.username + '</strong> <small>' + user.fullname + '</small>'
    }
  }
};

$('textarea').suggest({
  '@': optsObj,
  '#': optsObj
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I had gone through the doc but hadn't notice the multiple but you saved my day. Thank you so much.

Comment: How can I identify if the search is being done using @ or #?

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar Looks like this plugin doesn't handle it. One way could be to extend obj passed as option and set key property: `$('textarea').suggest({
  '@': $.extend({}, optsObj, {key: '@'}),
  '#': $.extend({}, optsObj, {key: '#'})
});`  Then inside any plugin callback, check for `this.key`. Or simply, for each key, pass different obj options. Now it is quite unclear to me how do you wish to check it. You should provide a jsFiddle replicating your issue and expected behaviour, i guess there is better way to do depending what you are looking for

Comment: I have done it. Thank you. I made another object for hash key.